What is this chip in a switching power supply marked IAFSN?
I am trying to identify chip on my constant current led driver.
I think it is monolithicpower's chip but couldn't find which one.
It's 6-pin, and marked as IAFSN


The I could be the pin 1 indicator, which would make the marking only AFSN.

Yes, it is indeed manufactured by Monolithic Power Systems. The IC is MP4026: Primary-Side-Control, Offline LED Controller with Active PFC.
